# PHP with multiple queries

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a code where I can update "records" of students from my database. The problem is there were multiple queries and being new to php as a whole, I don't know how to do it.

Below is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>PRACTICE 04</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '','student');
        if (!$link) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
        }
        echo 'Connected successfully';

        $IDNoOld = $_POST["IDNoOld"];
        $IDNoNew = $_POST["IDNoNew"];
        $FirstName = $_POST["FNameNew"];
        $MiddleName = $_POST["MNameNew"];
        $LastName = $_POST["LNameNew"];
        $Grade = $_POST["GradeNew"];
        $Sec = $_POST["SecNew"];
        $Add = $_POST["AddNew"];
        $Age = $_POST["AgeNew"];
        $FSub = $_POST["FSubNew"];
        $LSub = $_POST["LSubNew"];


        $sql_query = "UPDATE student1 SET IDNo='$IDNoNew' WHERE IDNo = '$IDNoOld'"; "UPDATE student1 SET FirstName='$FirstName' WHERE IDNo = '$IDNoOld'";
        echo $sql_query;
        
        $sql_query = "UPDATE student1 SET FirstName='$FirstName' WHERE IDNo = '$IDNoOld'";
        echo $sql_query;
        
        $sql_query = "UPDATE student1 SET MiddleName='$MiddleName' WHERE IDNo = '$IDNoOld'";
        echo $sql_query;
        
        $sql_query = "UPDATE student1 SET LastName='$LastName' WHERE IDNo = '$IDNoOld'";
        echo $sql_query;
        
        $sql_query = "UPDATE student1 SET Grade='$Grade' WHERE IDNo = '$IDNoOld'";
        echo $sql_query;
        
        $sql_query = "UPDATE student1 SET Section='$Sec' WHERE IDNo = '$IDNoOld'";
        echo $sql_query;
        
        $sql_query = "UPDATE student1 SET Address='$Add' WHERE IDNo = '$IDNoOld'";
        echo $sql_query;
        
        $sql_query = "UPDATE student1 SET Age='$Age' WHERE IDNo = '$IDNoOld'";
        echo $sql_query;
        
        $sql_query = "UPDATE student1 SET FavoriteSubject='$FSub' WHERE IDNo = '$IDNoOld'";
        echo $sql_query;
        
        $sql_query = "UPDATE student1 SET LeastFavoriteSubject='$LSub' WHERE IDNo = '$IDNoOld'";
        echo $sql_query;

        if (mysqli_query($link, $sql_query))
        {
            echo "Data successfully updated!";
        }


        mysqli_close($link);
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

A little help would absolutely help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: you can update multiple columns in 1 query, just use ",". 

SET IDNo='%s',  FirstName='%s'

Comment: and your query is prone to sql injection

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: The use of variables within the SQL directly is **not** the way to do it - you have exposed your code to SQL injection by doing so

Comment: You also cannot have two sql queries in the same `$sql_query` string using regular `mysqli_query`

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than many queries that update a single column you can, as mentioned, update multiple columns by specifying them as `name=value` pairs in the query separated by a comma. You would not however wish to embed the POST variables directly in the SQL as your database could very quickly become violated. Instead you should always use [Prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) when dealing with user supplied data - even when you think you can trust the user.

You could try something like this (untested)

```
<?php

    error_reporting( E_ALL );

    # Object Orientated syntax is less verbose than procedural!
    
    mysqli_report( MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT );
    $link = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '','student');
    
    # only proceed if ALL post variables are present
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset(
        $_POST['IDNoNew'],
        $_POST['FNameNew'],
        $_POST['MNameNew'],
        $_POST['LNameNew'],
        $_POST['GradeNew'],
        $_POST['SecNew'],
        $_POST['AddNew'],
        $_POST['AgeNew'],
        $_POST['FSubNew'],
        $_POST['LSubNew'],
        $_POST['IDNoOld']
    )){
        # construct the basic update command with placeholders for variable substitution
        $sql='update `student1` set `IDNo`=?, `FirstName`=?, `MiddleName`=?, `LastName`=?, `Grade`=?, `Section`=?, `Address`=?, `Age`=?, `FavoriteSubject`=?, `LeastFavoriteSubject`=? where `IDNo`=?';
        
        # the sequence here matches the placeholders!
        $args=array( 
            $_POST['IDNoNew'],
            $_POST['FNameNew'],
            $_POST['MNameNew'],
            $_POST['LNameNew'],
            $_POST['GradeNew'],
            $_POST['SecNew'],
            $_POST['AddNew'],
            $_POST['AgeNew'],
            $_POST['FSubNew'],
            $_POST['LSubNew'],
            $_POST['IDNoOld']
        );
        
        # create a string of variable types for use in the statement. String is OK here for all.
        $types=str_repeat('s',count( $args ) );

        # create the prepared statement, bind the params and execute.
        $stmt=$link->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bind_params( $types, ...$args );
        $stmt->execute();           
    }
?>
```